# Local: Host resolution failure in using Kafka with .net core

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am absolutely new in using Kafka.I have three servers that uses kafka and want to use them in my project as message broker. They were working perfectly but suddenly the problem started to occur .
The codes that I am trying to use are as follows:

```
>        using (var adminClient = new AdminClientBuilder(new AdminClientConfig { BootstrapServers = bootStrapServers }).Build())
>                     {
>                         try
>                         {
>                             var topicInfo = adminClient.GetMetadata(topicName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
>         
>                             
>                             if (topicInfo.Topics.Where(x => x.Error.IsError).Count() == 0)
>                                 await adminClient.DeleteTopicsAsync(new List<string>() { topicName });
>         
>                             await adminClient.CreateTopicsAsync(new TopicSpecification[] {
>                             new TopicSpecification { Name = topicName, ReplicationFactor = 1, NumPartitions = 1 } });
>         
>         
>                         }
>                         catch (CreateTopicsException e)
>                         {
>                             Console.WriteLine($"An error occured creating topic {e.Results[0].Topic}: {e.Results[0].Error.Reason}");
>                         }
>                     }
```

by performing this line of Codes:

> var topicInfo = adminClient.GetMetadata(topicName,
> TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

the host name of each broker change to something like that **zk-kafka-test245** and the brokerOriginating property is equal to -1 and the runtime error

> 'Local: Host resolution failure' raises.